# Template Class Operator Overloading C++

Tags: templates, c++17, operator-overloading

I am experiencing trouble with overloading binary operators in c++17. I have a class template that reads:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class MyClass1
{
public:

    // Overloaded + operator.
    MyClass1<T> operator + (const T value)
    {
        MyClass1<T> vector0 = MyClass1<T>();

        for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) vector0[i] = container[i] + value;

        return vector0;
    }

    // Overloaded + operator.
    T& operator [] (size_t index)
    {
        return container[index];
    }

    // Constructor.
    MyClass1()
    {
        container = std::vector<T>(3, (T) 0);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> container{};
};


int main()
{
  MyClass1 temp = MyClass(3);
  temp = temp + 1;   // Works perfectly!

  return 0;
}
```

But when I want to overload from both sides:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class MyClass1
{
public:

    // Overloaded + operator.
    MyClass1<T> operator + (const MyClass1<T> & vector, const T value)
    {
        MyClass1<T> vector0 = MyClass1<T>();

        for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) vector0[i] = vector[i] + value;

        return vector0;
    }

    // Overloaded + operator.
    T& operator [] (size_t index)
    {
        return container[index];
    }

    // Constructor.
    MyClass1()
    {
        container = std::vector<T>(3, (T) 0);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> container{};
};


int main()
{
  MyClass1 temp = MyClass(3);
  temp = temp + 1;   // FAILS!

  return 0;
}
```

The error message is:
"error: invalid operands to binary expression ('MyClass1' and 'int') test = test + 1;"

I understand the message, but I can't find a way to fix it. It is puzzling, since it's the standard way to do it.

### Why?

Trying to imitate Python's numpy array functionality for a small project in C++. I can always leave it as the first one, but it becomes annoying when following standard mathematical notation for, say, multiplication.

### More Potentially Useful Information

Compiling with an old MAC:

Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29),
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0,
Thread model: posix.

Running as:

```bash
$ c++ -std=c++17 -o test test.cpp
$ ./test
```

This is supposed to be standard but it's not working.

### Question

What is going on?

Comment: Not quite, what is happening is that I write the code and I know how to write the code, but my compiler (I think it must be), is complaining about the form of the expression. I have no idea if it's the compiler or that the program is flawed...the latter being the most likely.

Comment: Member `operator+` takes zero or one argument. Your compiler doesn't complain about that?

Comment: As pointed out, the first piece of code works fine and compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: We're talking about the second piece of code, where you violated that rule. Your compiler should report an error like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5x1Y3cPWq). Maybe you forgot `friend` in your post?

Comment: I might have...had not noticed that it needed the "friend" modifier.

Comment: I tried to set the function as friend, but the problem now is that I cannot access non-static members of my class. So, in summary, just learn how to live with the right-hand operator?

Comment: Friend function is like a non-member function, but gives access to non-public members. You take the object as an argument, just use `obj.member` instead of `this->member`.

Comment: I will try it and let you know what happens. Thanks!